# Align header same size

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a header and I would like to align all in there with the same size.

My script in CSS:

```css
.navbar .navbar-inner {
    padding: 0;
  }
  .navbar .nav {
    margin: 0;
    display: table-cell;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .navbar .nav  {
    display: table-cell;
  }
  .navbar .nav li {
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    border-left: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,.75);
    border-right: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.1);
  }
  .navbar .nav li:first-child a {
    border-left: 0;
    border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
  }
  .navbar .nav li:last-child a {
    border-right: 0;
    border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  }
```

My HTML header:

```
<div class="navbar">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="container">
            <ul class="nav">
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Topic<b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="test.php">Topic 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="test.php">Topic 2/a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>               
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div><!-- /.navbar -->
```

Comment: Can you provide more information, preferably a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) example? Please show your HTML as well.

Comment: its hard, because I dont know how to add bootstrap in this website. But I will edit and write my header code that I have forgotten.

Comment: I didnt have much space to put all script. ):

Comment: Is there any class specifying different widths to any of these elements in your debug inspector? Otherwise, try adding box-size: border-box to each of your elements, it should help determine if its padding + width issue.

Comment: It didnt work. My website is this one: http://testeunicamp.netau.net/contato.php
You can see the header there, I just want to align in the same size.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean, this:

```
 .container{
border:1px solid #ddd;
 }
.navbar .navbar-inner {
  padding: 0;
}
.navbar .nav {
  margin: 0;
  display: table-cell;
  width: 100%;
 }
.navbar .nav  {
  display: table-cell;
}
.navbar .nav li {
   font-weight: bold;
   text-align: center;
   border-left: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,.75);
   border-right: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.1);
   clear:both;
 }
 .navbar .nav li a{
    border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
    display: block;
    float: left;
     height: 40px;
     padding: 10px;
     width: 83px;
   }
   .navbar .nav li:hover .dropdown-menu{
      display:block;
      text-align:left;
      min-width:83px !important;
      top:41px;
      padding:0;
      margin:0;
     left:-2px;
   }
```